# Unable to save file in server with tcpdf

Tags: php

```
$html = <<<EOD
EOD;
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $table, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
$pdf->Output('order/orders_2013-10.pdf', 'F');
```

This is the code i use to create and save a pdf file and it worked well on my local wamp server but when i run it over a windows iis webserver pdf is not created and reflects with the below error.

**TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: order\orders_2013-10.pdf**

I am new to php please help me...

Comment: Make sure you have the folder named `order` in the respective directory.

Comment: And the required permissions (`chmod`) are set

Answer (score 0):

make sure that **your file('order/orders_2013-10.pdf')** is not open anywhere when you run the script. if it's open somewhere else then TCPDF can't open it.